# Saving Activity State when switching activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently trying to create an activity, which should be creating a new TextView on my main activity, everytime a Button is clicked on the first activity. However, instead of creating a new TextView everytime the button is clicked, it just changes the values of the first created TextView, so that there is always only one TextView. Is there a way to make it so that my first activity will not only create one single textview?

Here's the code from my "NewSubjectActivity":

```
**public class NewSubjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_subject);

    Button SaveBtn = findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
    nsaSaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Click();
        }
    });
}



protected void Click(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(NewSubjectActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

    Boolean createnewTextView = true;

    intent.putExtra("createnewTextView",createnewTextView);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

And here's the (relevant) code from my MainActivity:

```
 protected void ReceiveValue (){


    //getting Extras
    Intent nsareceivedvalues = getIntent();


        boolean createTextView = false;
        createTextView = nsareceivedvalues.getExtras().getBoolean("createnewTextView");

        //declaring fixed Views
        final LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);




        //Params for TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 200);
        Params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);

        while(createTextView) {
            //creating a TextView
            TextView newsubject = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

            //applying values to the TextView
            newsubject.setLayoutParams(Params);
            newsubject.setGravity(CENTER);
            newsubject.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            mainLinearLayout.addView(newsubject);
            createTextView = false; 
        }

}
```

As I said, this only create one text view, everytime I press the button on my "NewSubjectActivity" I think this might be, because the previous text view is not saved and the MainActivity is reset everytime I switch between the activities.

Every help and advise is much appreciated <3

Comment: Can you please check if it enter the while loop or not? If not then it will be the logical prooblem. Please let me know

Comment: I now used another TextView which changes the text, when the loop is entered and it works, so the loop is entered..

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: @MuktaGhosh no, nothing changed, I just figured out, that it wasn't the loop..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you are going back to your main activity you should call to onBackPressed() function, so it will reset nothing at all. Here's the example in kotlin

```
val back_button:Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
    back_button.setOnClickListener { v -> run {
        //Change activity
        onBackPressed()
} }
```

in Java should be:

```
Button back_button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Change activity
        onBackPressed()
    }
});
```

Let's hope it works!